# Move into the sub directories conflict with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdirectory

the structure of my website is as following

- Website

  - inc/

    - sub-directory/
    - header.php
    - content.php
    - footer.php
  - index.php
  - `.htaccess`

Now in my `.htaccess`, I have done the `URL Re-writing` in such way `http://my_website/page/s/o`. Now I want to move into sub-directory but it is taking the first parameter as `page`, and its not entering into the sub directory. I cannot place sub-directory on root (to avoid the redefining of template structure)

below is my `.htaccess` file

```
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out how to distunguish the "real" subdirectory requests from those targeting index.php. I assume that you only have a limited set of actual subdirectories, and that those do not conflict with the `/page/s/o` scheme. For example, if `www.mysite.com/users/x/y` were a valid request, you cannot have an actual `/users` subdirectory.

To filter out the actual subdirectory-targeted requests, make a RewriteRule statement that "catches" the real subdirectories:

```
RewriteRule ^/realsubdir - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/([^/]+)?$ index\.php?page=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})/?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})?$ index\.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The dash (-) in the substitution part means: leave the path unchanged, i.e. no substitution taking place.